# CodeIgniter button that works like href

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, button, codeigniter-3

I have this button

```
 <a class="btn btn-sm btn-success" href="javascript:void(0)" title="info" onclick="delete_province('."'".$info->ID."'".')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></i> Show File</a>';
```

that i want to change that button function with something like this

```
<a href = '<?php echo base_url().'Employees/updatepersonalinfo/'.$data; ?>' class = 'btn btn-info pull-right fa fa-edit'>&nbsp Update</a>
```

please notice here

`echo base_url().'Employees/updatepersonalinfo/'.$data;`

that im passing a data at the url for me to use the function `$this->uri->segment()`

how can i make the button work like href? and is there any other way that the templates wont load anymore just some of the div? thanks in advance

and also the `.$data` that i want to pass came from , a json?

heres additional codes to be clear

here is the controller with the button

```
public function index()
{

    $data['content_view'] = 'TaxValues/taxvalues_read';
    $this->templates->admin_template($data);
}

public function ajax_list()
{
    $list = $this->TaxValues_Model->get_datatables();
    $data = array();
    $no = $_POST['start'];
    foreach ($list as $info) {
        $no++;
        $row = array();
        $row[] = $info->RANGE_NO;
        $row[] = $info->TAX;
        $row[] = $info->PERCENTAGE." %";
        $row[] = $info->VALUE;
        $row[] = $info->FREQUENCY;

        //add html for action
        $row[] = '<a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Edit" onclick="edit_provinces('."'".$info->TAX_ID."'".')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i> Edit</a>
              <a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Delete" onclick="delete_province('."'".$info->TAX_ID."'".')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i> Delete</a>';

        $data[] = $row;
    }

    $output = array(
                    "draw" => $_POST['draw'],
                    "recordsTotal" => $this->TaxValues_Model->count_all(),
                    "recordsFiltered" => $this->TaxValues_Model->count_filtered(),
                    "data" => $data,
            );
    //output to json format
    echo json_encode($output);
}
```

i wanted to pass the `$info->TAX_ID` so that for example, i want to access my existing update code,

controller function of update

```
public function updateinfo(){

    $data['content'] = $this->TaxValues_Model->info();
    $data['content_view'] = 'TaxValues/edit';
    $this->templates->admin_template($data);

}
```

model function of update

```
public function info(){

    $query = $this->db->get_where('emp_fi_p', array('ID_NUM' => $this->uri->segment(3)));
    return $query->row();
}
```

Comment: That is not a button but `<a>` which has `href` attribute... What is not working ?

Comment: @Rayon i revised it. haha. i want to do `href = '<?php echo base_url().'Employees/updatepersonalinfo/'.$data; ?>'` but the value `$data` came from javascript i want to put it on my url.

Comment: `$data` comes from JavaScript ? Or php ?

Comment: What exactly do you want? change `href` action on `click` ?

Comment: yes. and i need to pass a value on that href link. :)

Comment: can you please post your code little more.?

Comment: @Gopal i have updated the question.